# .net clear IBM mq programatically

Tags: c#, .net, ibm-mq

Is there anyway to clear the IBM Queue programatically? I want to clear all messages for some queues at a certain time everyday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a simple program to consume all messages on the queue.  If the IPPROCS and OPPROCS are both zero then you can write a program to issue the PCF ClearQ command or the runmqsc ClearQ command.  I've written about [how to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67323366/consume-all-messages-from-ibm-mq/67341244#67341244) and so have other MQ users.  Try doing an internet search.

Answer (score 0):

you can find some good options for your question here => [Automatically clear messages from queue in IBM MQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12924543/automatically-clear-messages-from-queue-in-ibm-mq/68549401#68549401)

the easiest way would be to schedule the 'amqsget' sample program and just consume messages from queue and don't store them on disk (it's called a destructive MQGET).

Comment: amqsget can't handle larger messages.  If you want to run a program to do a destructive get dmpmqmsg is a much better option, just use the purge option.

Comment: True, didn't think of that. However you could just alter the maximum message length in the amqsget code and recompile it but using dmpmqmsg would indeed be the most time and effort effective option